# How do I use two variables in title of a plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, graphics, latex

How do I use variables in Latex expressions in R?

For example:

`a<-5;
b<-1;
plot(X, Y, main=expression(paste(p==a,q==b)))`

`a` and `b` are R variables. Also I want to have "," in Output?
How do I do that?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: for example p=5,q=1; (5 and 1 are values of R variables.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `substitute` instead of `expression`. The second argument is a list specifying replacement strings and objects.

```
a <- 5
b <- 1
plot(1, 1, main = substitute(paste(p == a, ", ", q == b), list(a = a, b = b)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Instead of expression you can use `bquote()` to get desired effect. `.(a)` ensures that it is replaced by actual `a` value, `*","` adds comma to the expression.

```
a<-5
b<-1 
plot(1:10, main=bquote(p==.(a) *"," ~q==.(b)))
```

[image]